# Redirect 302 not working in htaccess file

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm doing what I thought would be a simple task.  Using an .htaccess file I want to redirect from one page to another page.

This is my redirect statement:

```
Redirect 302 /myfavoritebook https://play.google.com/store/books/...
```

When I put in the path:

```
www.mywebsite.com/myfavoritebook
```

It takes me to a custom 404 missing page that I created.  It doesn't redirect me to the new website.

Any thoughts on why?

Comment: Are you calling the link for the first time or have you called it BEFORE setting the 302 redirect? Maybe your webbrowser cached the 404 error + you need to clear the browser cache before propery getting redirected?

Comment: I just tried your `Redirect` in my test environment and it works as expected, redirecting to Google play. There could be many reasons, other rules, browser caching responses, proxy caching responses, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks. For more complicated tasks such as manipulating the query string, use the tools provided by mod_rewrite.

You may try using `mod_rewrite` instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myfavoritebook/?  https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Orson_Scott_Card_Ender_s_Game?id=Ojqi8KbWuLwC&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImJvb2stT2pxaThLYld1THdDIl0  [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: I didn't see OP using query string. OP wrote: `When I put in the path:

www.mywebsite.com/myfavoritebook`

Comment: Yep, this worked, however, I'm still wondering why my "Redirect" statement didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your rule looks fine to me, but I have seen many times `mod_alias` doesn't work with queries, whether they are originally at the request or the redirected URL. That's why I suggest using `mod_rewrite` in those cases. I have also seen the opposite, though, but in this case did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Well... it did, so I'm giving you the correct answer, but it still would have been nice to understand why Redirect itself didn't work.

Comment: Agree. I don't think it is because your rule is wrong, though.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry I didn't respond to your comment before, but yes, there is no query in the request. There is one in the redirected URL, though. As I say in my comments here, I am not sure why the OP redirect doesn't work, but it seems the solution in these cases is to use `mod_rewrite` instead, as Apache suggests.